# How to create header menu for multiple page in powerapss?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I want to create horizontal header menu that can navigate to
multiple page below it but  do not want to duplicate it for each page.

Note: The horizontal header menu is not a duplicated for the multi page

Comment: Show us what you did till now and also few screenshots will be helpful. What exactly is your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The experimental feature [Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/create-component) can be used for this. The link has an example vertical menu that you can customize to be horizontal. Microsoft also has an example [Tab Control](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-ten-reusable-components/) that may be useful.